# Can't pull from Heroku. Couldn't find remote ref master

Tags: git, heroku

This is what I did:

```
heroku git:remote -a myapp

git pull heroku master

fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master
```

myapp is an existing project, it is not new.

What am I doing wrong? How can I pull from Heroku?. Which branch name should I use?

**Edit**

The output of git remote -v:

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git (push)
origin  git@git.fullstack.ec:misuper/myapp.git (fetch)
origin  git@git.fullstack.ec:misuper/myapp.git (push)
```

Also, I tried `git clone` in a new folder and it gives me the message "You appear to have cloned an empty repository". It is not empty.

And I tried doing the same thing with a different app and it worked correctly.

I'm lost here.

Comment: What is the output of 'git branch -a'?

Comment: @JackBracken
new_apps
  remotes/origin/NewProjectTree
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/staging

Can't find Heroku there

Comment: And git remote -v? Looking through the heroku docs, the command 'heroku git:remote -a myapp' will only set up your git remote on a (presumably) new heroku project, so it should be empty, and it makes sense that git pull complains about the branch master not existing--nothing has been pushed to your heroku remote yet. Try 'git push heroku master'

Comment: @JackBracken it is an existing project. I can't push without pulling first. Or at least I shouldn't ... is there a workaround for this? thanks for your help man.

Comment: The way a typical heroku workflow goes, as I recall, is you work locally with a git repo, then create a heroku app and set up a heroku git remote with the command line, and push your app to that heroku remote. If the app is a pre-existing one (and for example you can see it working by going to that heroku app's URL), then I'm not sure why no it can't find the remote master ref. What was the output of 'git remote -v'?

Comment: @JackBracken I added some edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things to consider, and hopefully get you moving:

- While Heroku uses 'git' to manage the movement of code to/from Heroku, it is itself not a code repository in the more general sense of Github
- use `heroku git:clone -a your-app-name` to clone an existing app into your local project directory
- use `git push heroku master` to push your code to Heroku for execution

You should be using Github or some other version control system to manage the actual lifecycle of your source code, eg Pulls, Branches, Merges, &c...

Regarding the error you ran into when trying to execute the `heroku git:clone...` - how did the application `myapp` come to be in Heroku in the first place? If you initially created the app using the Heroku **Button** on a Github repo, there is a bug today which results in the app being created, and the code deployed, but the source is not stored in the internal Heroku repo. If this is the case you will need to

1. `git clone` the original repo to a local dir
2. `heroku git:remote -a myapp` to add Heroku as a remote repo
3. `git push heroku master` to deploy the code to the Heroku repo